# Using viewpoint make some lines thinner than others

Tags: css, reactjs

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column
  }

.container {
  width: 80vw;
  flex: 1;
  text-decoration: none;

 
}
.content {
  flex-grow: 1;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 80vw;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 4.5% 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.bar {
  width: 80%;
  height:0.5vw;
  background: black;
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="content"></div>
    <div class="bar"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="content"></div>
    <div class="bar"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="content"></div>
    <div class="bar"></div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Hi I am setting the line height with viewpoint but sometimes it makes lines thinner than other lines although it has exactly same height, and I cannot really give fixed size for height because other things built with viewpoint already
Is there any way to fix this problem ? 
If you change window size, you will notice some lines are 1px or more thinner than others. I am guessing it cannot round 0.123123123 things

Comment: Can you provide some code?